# How to reload datagridview in vbnet with sql server database

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, vb.net, datagridview

I'm still learning in programming from ebook and Internet. Currently, I'm interested in creating database application using vb.net for the interface and Sql Server for database.

My project is simple add, save, edit, delete records in database.

Here is my code

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class FormCabinet

    'Variable Declaration
    Dim CabinetCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim CabinetAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim CabinetTable As DataTable
    Dim CabinetManager As CurrencyManager
    Dim MyState As String, MyBookmark As Integer

    Private Sub FormCabinet_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            Call OPENCONN()

            CabinetCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [CABINET]", CONN)
            CabinetAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
            CabinetAdapter.SelectCommand = CabinetCommand
            CabinetTable = New DataTable()
            CabinetAdapter.Fill(CabinetTable)

            'bind control to data table
            TbCabID.DataBindings.Add("Text", CabinetTable, "CABINET_ID")
            TbCabinet.DataBindings.Add("Text", CabinetTable, "CAB_TAG")
            TbDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", CabinetTable, "CAB_DESC")

            'establish currency manager
            CabinetManager = DirectCast(Me.BindingContext(CabinetTable), CurrencyManager)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error establishing Cabinet Table", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        Me.Show()

        Call SetState("View")

    End Sub

    Private Sub FormCabinet_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        If MyState = "Edit" Or MyState = "Add" Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must finish current edit before closing the form", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            'exit cancel procedure
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            Try
                'save changes to database
                Dim CabinetAdapterCommands As New SqlCommandBuilder(CabinetAdapter)
                CabinetAdapter.Update(CabinetTable)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error saving database to file:" + ControlChars.CrLf + ex.Message, "Save Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
            'close connection
            CONN.Close()
            'dispose of objects
            CabinetCommand.Dispose()
            CabinetAdapter.Dispose()
            CabinetTable.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

    'Sub setState
    Private Sub SetState(ByVal AppState As String)
        MyState = AppState
        Select Case AppState
            Case "View"
                BtnFirst.Enabled = True
                BtnPrevious.Enabled = True
                BtnNext.Enabled = True
                BtnLast.Enabled = True
                BtnEdit.Enabled = True
                BtnSave.Enabled = False
                BtnCancel.Enabled = False
                BtnAdd.Enabled = True
                TbCabID.ReadOnly = True
                TbCabinet.ReadOnly = True
                TbDescription.ReadOnly = True
            Case "Add", "Edit"
                BtnFirst.Enabled = False
                BtnPrevious.Enabled = False
                BtnNext.Enabled = False
                BtnLast.Enabled = False
                BtnEdit.Enabled = False
                BtnSave.Enabled = True
                BtnCancel.Enabled = True
                BtnAdd.Enabled = False
                TbCabID.ReadOnly = False
                TbCabinet.ReadOnly = False
                TbDescription.ReadOnly = False
        End Select

    End Sub

    'Input Validation
    Private Function ValidateData() As Boolean
        Dim Message As String = ""
        Dim AllOK As Boolean = True
        'Check for name 
        If TbCabinet.Text.Trim = "" Then
            Message = "You must enter an Cabinet Name." + ControlChars.CrLf
            TbCabinet.Focus()
            AllOK = False
        End If
        If Not (AllOK) Then
            MessageBox.Show(Message, "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
        Return (AllOK)
    End Function

    Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
        Try
            MyBookmark = CabinetManager.Position
            CabinetManager.AddNew()
            Call SetState("Add")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error adding record.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDelete.Click
        Dim Response As Windows.Forms.DialogResult
        Response = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)
        'show dialogue
        If Response = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'if yes then delete at current position
        Try
            CabinetManager.RemoveAt(CabinetManager.Position)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error deleting record.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Button Cancel
    Private Sub BtnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCancel.Click
        CabinetManager.CancelCurrentEdit()
        If MyState = "Add" Then
            CabinetManager.Position = MyBookmark
        End If
        Call SetState("View")
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEdit.Click
        Call SetState("Edit")
    End Sub

    'Button Save
    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
        If Not (ValidateData()) Then Exit Sub
        Dim SavedName As String = TbCabID.Text
        Dim SavedRow As Integer
        Try
            CabinetManager.EndCurrentEdit()
            CabinetTable.DefaultView.Sort = "CABINET_ID"
            SavedRow = CabinetTable.DefaultView.Find(SavedName)
            CabinetManager.Position = SavedRow
            MessageBox.Show("Record Saved", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Call SetState("View")


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error saving record.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm trying to add DataGridView in my Form. However, after I add a DataGridView using this subroutine and call it in my FormCabinet_Load, I can't save the records again.

```vb
Sub ShowGrid()

    Call OPENCONN()
    CabinetCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT [CABINET_ID] AS 'CABINET ID', [CAB_TAG] AS 'TAG NUMBER', [CAB_DESC] AS 'DESCRIPTION' FROM [CABINET] ORDER BY CABINET_ID", CONN)
    CabinetAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
    CabinetAdapter.SelectCommand = CabinetCommand
    CabinetTable = New DataTable()
    CabinetAdapter.Fill(CabinetTable)   
    DataGridView1.DataSource = CabinetTable

End Sub
```

I have tried to call `ShowGrid()` in the end of the `BtnSave_click` subrotine, and

```vb
CabinetAdapter.Update(CabinetTable)
```

in order to update the database right away. However it only works one time. I need to close the Form and start it from the beginning to edit my database.

How to reload/refresh the DataGridView?

Any advice or link is appreciated
Kindly Please let me know if you need further information

Comment: Try adding `DataGridView1.Refresh()` after assigning `DataGridView1.DataSource`. Note that you need to repeat rebinding of `DataGridView` data source after every CRUD operation.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) I created that you can use as a guide. One of the keys to using data adapters is to store an instance at the class level instead of recreating it on method calls. The adapter and dataset track changes and  you throw all of that away when you declare them local to methods.

Comment: @Crowcoder I checked out the link. Have you had bad results with the SQLCommandBuilder? It would save some code.

Comment: I don't like SqlCommandBuilder because I like to make sure the command that I expect is the one that is being executed. It also has limitations if you don't have a very straightforward table.

Comment: @Crowcoder, wow what a nice web you have, ill try it on.. 
Also do you have any example for interfacing with relational database?, i mean like a simple input (using combobox and fill it with value from table A which is a parent table) then input it into the child table.. Sorry if i ask a lot i really don't get it enough

Comment: Yes, that example demonstrates a combobox and it is backed by an MS SQL Server database.